# how to convert udp session captured in pcap file wireshark to readable ascii format

Tags: networking

I've captured  my port  o/p in wireshark  pcap file which is udp stream , I've pasted o/p wireshark here, though its said in wireshak that its ascii format still its not clerarly readable and could I get help so I can filter this stream to be readable ...same happens when when I'm trying to read SNMP strings in pcap file kindly suggest to convert it to become readable.

> ".4........New callers: 76         ".4......|".4........

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clearly enough stated for me to understand exactly what you want.  But I *think* you're looking for as much parsing as possible of a file in a textual output.  If so, consider using `tshark` with it's -V switch turned on which will display a packet to the maximum ability that the wireshark engine can parse but in text output rather than via the graphical tree.

Comment: Ya I've checked for tshark -V -r file_to_convert.pcap

command. but my tshark.exe  is not allowing me to do anything. As soon I execute tshark it directly starts capturing.Can I have info where to put above said command in order to convert pcap file stored into text file ??

Comment: Run tshark from the cmd shell using the -r switch to read in the pcap file

Comment: Hi.. ur last comment was helpful for me. Going further suppose I have captured an session of ip camera in pcap file via wireshark .Is it possible to recover origional video frames in jpeg format with any application. host and camera is using udp for conversation...